# Are there any in-game hints towards the evolution methods for story-based Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

After many hours of trying to keep the game spoiler-free as best I could, I eventually looked online the methods to evolve the mountable Pokemon, particularly [Basculegion](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Basculegion_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), [Ursaluna](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ursaluna_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), and [Wyrdeer](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Wyrdeer_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). These Pokemon have pretty unique and specific evolution methods.

Basculin

> evolves into Basculegion after losing at least 294 HP from recoil damage,

Ursaring

> evolves into Ursluna when exposed to a Peat Block during a full moon

and Stantler

> evolves into  Wyrdeer  after using Psyshield Bash in Agile Style at least 20 times

While I caved and looked online, I have friends who are wanting to stay clear of looking anything online. Given how these Pokemon play a part in the story, are there any in-game hints towards how to evolve these Pokemon for Pokedex entries?

Comment: Mountable? Wait, you mean you can further evolve the pokemon you mount (pressing ➕)? Or are you talking about evolving regular pokemon to obtain those evolutions?

Comment: After looking at the title, I guess I word it confusingly. I’m talking about the latter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Basculin and Stantler, while there are not direct hints,

> Both have entries directly related in their Pokédex research tasks that, if accomplished by a single Pokémon, would allow it to evolve.

I would not consider Uraaluna’s method particularly unique, other Pokémon have had essentially identical elements before, and

> The name does suggest the harder part of the evolution…

Comment: [faceplam] I didn’t even think to consider to check that for Basculin and Stantler. I figured Ursaluna's name at had something to do with it, but alas puzzles aren’t my strong suit

Comment: Wait for the Unowndex then… :)

Comment: Unfortunately for french players, Usraluna is named 'Ursaking', which remove the critical clue.